# The Quotation Environment

Tags: environments

I am trying to make a quotation environment as picture below.

[image]

The environment is indented the same as `\parindent` on each side, the environment is automatically italic, and you can put the person and the date in brackets not in italics.

I don't have an MWE since I'm not really sure where to start. I guess it's something to do with `\newinvironment`, but I've never used that before.

Could someone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Your document class probably already contains a `quote` and a `quotation` environment, with slightly different formats, and one of them might be exactly what you want. The simplest way to get the attribution at the right margin is just to put `\hfill` in front of it - though if you have a lot of quotes and you need to automatically handle the situation where the attribution needs to go on a separate line because it won't fit on the last line of the quote, you might want a more sophisticated alternative. If so, ask another question just about that.

Comment: To customise a quote/quotation environment, take a look at the `quoting` package. Another posssibility: the `epigraph` package.

Comment: @alephzero ok good point. It'd be nice if I could do it automatically. But I guess that'll do. Also thanks to Bernard for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `quoting` package is very useful, together with a trick found in the TeXbook (look for Bourbaki in the index).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quoting,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bywhom}{m}{% the Bourbaki trick
  {\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
   \hfill\mbox{\normalfont(#1)}%
   \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pquotation}{m}
  {\begin{quoting}[
     indentfirst=true,
     leftmargin=\parindent,
     rightmargin=\parindent]\itshape}
  {\bywhom{#1}\end{quoting}}

\begin{document}

This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
\begin{pquotation}{Jack Johnson, 2003}
`This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation.'
\end{pquotation}
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
\begin{pquotation}{Jack Johnson, 2003}
`This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.
This is a quotation. This is a quotation.'
\end{pquotation}
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.
This is not a quotation, this is normal text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solved my current problem. It feels a bit overkill to need to load a new package to be able to do this, but if that's how LaTeX does things...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It would of course be possible to do it "package-free”, but why reinventing the wheel? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution based on the `csquotes` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% filler text:
\newcommand\lipx{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, 
felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam 
arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, 
vulputate a, magna.}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockThreshold{2}
\newcommand\myblockquote[2]{%
  \blockquote{\hspace*{2em}\emph{`#1'}\hfill(#2)}\par}

\begin{document}
\lipx\ \lipx

\myblockquote{\lipx}{Jack Johnson, 2003}

\lipx\ \lipx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add some words to the quotation and see what happens. A possible  failure is that the name may be split across lines; the second, less obvious failure is when the `\hfill` is used as a line break point, whence the name will be flush left.