# Unwanted space (wrong formatting)

Tags: spacing, formatting

when compiled the call to the macros insert extra space between the words and the "[3 Min]" is put in two lines.
Why?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\textbf{Aufgabe #1: {\thesection}}}

\def\mytcolorbox#1#2#3%
{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}%
    #1\hfill[#2 Min]%
    \tcblower%
    #3%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mytcolorbox{\test{hello} text 1 text2 text 3 and so on...}{3}{great}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Also don't use def to define macros unless you really know what you are doing

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: I added the document class `beamer` to the example, assuming you are using this. However, compiling the example I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. There neither is extra space nor a split `[3 Min]` text.

Comment: The example compiled as expected on my system using the redacted MWE. However, `#1\hfill[#2 Min]` can have a line break at the space between the parameter and `Min`, if the PO add some text not disclosed for us, or use a bigger font size. Maybe enclosing it in a `\mbox{}` is a cure, _i.e._ `#1\hfill\mbox{[#2 Min]}`. At least that will move the whole box to the next line so that the problem will be easier to track.

Comment: Thank you Sveinung! That helped!

Answer (score 1):

If your [3 Min] has to go to the right margin, you need something more complicated than just adding `~` between `#2` and `Min`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\textbf{Aufgabe #1: {\thesection}}}

\newcommand\mytcolorbox[3]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    #1\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
    \hfill\mbox{[#2 Min]}%
    {\parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}
    \tcblower
    #3%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mytcolorbox{\test{hello} text 1 text2 text 3 text 4 and so on...}{3}{great}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391739/4427 for some more information.

[image]

Without `text 4`:

[image]