# How to place “theorem” flush right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]
how to align in the right side? to result like in the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl blabla blabla blabl
\newline\hspace*{\fill}\textbf{(theorem 1)}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @mico

Comment: What if the last line is short? You'll get a big hole.

Comment: Besides, `\null` is not a documented command and `\hspace*{\fill}` should be used instead of `\null\hfill`.

Comment: @Mico I read a few times the LaTeX manual and I can assure you that `\null` is not metioned. `;-)`

Comment: How does the fill know what to fill against? What happens when the enumerate has multiple items?

Comment: @Mast - Hopefully, the OP will see fit and provide some highly prized answers to your questions. (You don't expect me to know the OP's intentions, do you?)

Comment: Of-course not, I'm trying to understand how the code you provided in your answer does what it does.

Comment: @Mast - Thanks for clarifying. There's absolutely nothing automatic about the insertion method I suggest. If there are multiple `\item` statements and if the OP wants multiple insertions (one per `\item`, say), s/he will have to provide all needed `newline\hspace*{\fill}\textbf{...}` and `\hspace*{\fill}\textbf{...}` statements; omit `\newline` to avoid unsightly gaps. The OP didn't exactly provide an overabundance of information about his/her intentions. My answer assumes that `1.` is produced by an `enumerate` environment; however, that's clearly just a conjecture, nothing more...

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it :-)

Answer (score 11):

You don't want the remark to go to the next line if the last line of the paragraph is short.

Here I propose a better solution, comparing to the output one gets with the code suggested by Mico.

[image]

As you see, the other proposal leaves big holes in the second and third case.

The code below comes from [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391739/4427).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\what}[1]{% the Bourbaki trick
  \unskip{\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
   \hfill\mbox{\normalfont\bfseries(#1)}%
   \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{My proposal}

\begin{enumerate}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\what{Theorem 1}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
\what{Theorem 1}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\what{Theorem 1}

\end{enumerate}

\section{Less attractive output}

\begin{enumerate}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\newline\null\hfill\textbf{(theorem 1)}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
\newline\null\hfill\textbf{(theorem 1)}

\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\newline\null\hfill\textbf{(theorem 1)}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, that's not the result of another answer, which in the test case is good. Check the picture. However, I'll change the wording.

Comment: thanks a lot! it helps me so much.