Push text to right side within center align
I am writing a document that has some verses. Each verse block is center-aligned using the \begin{center}...\end{center} approach.
In addition, I would like to add the verse's reference on the last line (end of 2nd line in the verse below) and flush it to the right.
Use of the \rightline pushes the reference to the next line (even though there's plenty of hspace to place the ref on the same line). This results in many unnecessary extra lines in the document.
\begin{center}
अविनयमपनय विष्णो! दमय मनः शामय विषय-मृगतृष्णाम्‌ ।
भूतदयां विस्तारय, तारय संसार-सागरतः ॥ \rightline{--षट्पदी स्त्रोत्रम्‌}
\end{center}

My first approach \hfill messes up the center alignment of the centered block. I have seen suggestions about creating a table structure or a mini page to achieve desired result, which seems excessive to me. What I want is similar to equation numbers in equation context. Is there any existing package/command that does it?

You are probably looking for some variant of quote environment.  See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391726/the-quotation-environment

Beware! If the text at the far right is long, overlap can occur, because the material at the far right is set in a zero-width box.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\newcommand{\atright}[1]{%
  \unskip % remove a possible space in front
  \hfil % glue for centering
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#1}% the tag at the right
  \hfilneg % to countermand the \rightskip
  \hspace{0pt}% \par removes a glob of glue
  \par % ensure the line is ended
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[76][1-4]

\begin{center}
This is the first line of the poem \\
This is the second line of the poem\atright{--something}
\end{center}

\lipsum[77][1-4]

\end{document}



Accepting this solution as it requires minimal changes to my existing code and covers 95% of the verses. Remaining 5% I'll use \rightline and let the ref pushed to the next line.

Here's a solution that employs the tag* macro that's provided by the amsmath package. The macro \myverse takes 2 mandatory and 1 optional argument. The mandatory arguments are the verse and the "tag"; the optional argument is the (fractional) width of the minipage that contains the verse. If the optional argument isn't specified, the default is 0.6, for a width of 0.6\textwidth. The text of the verse is centered horizontally on the text block, i.e., its position is not influenced by the width of the tag.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex % or 'xelatex'
\documentclass{article}% or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{showframe} % optional: draw frameline around text block
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for '\tag*' macro
\usepackage{fontspec}  % for '\setmainfont' macro
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari} % select a suitable document font

\newcommand{\myverse}[3][0.6]{%
  \[
  \clap{\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
     \centering #2 \end{minipage}}
  \tag*{--#3}
  \]
  }
\begin{document}

\myverse{अविनयमपनय विष्णो! दमय मनः शामय विषय-मृगतृष्णाम्‌ । भूतदयां विस्तारय, तारय संसार-सागरतः ॥}{षट्पदी स्त्रोत्रम्}

\myverse[0.5]{अविनयमपनय विष्णो! दमय मनः शामय विषय-मृगतृष्णाम्‌ । भूतदयां विस्तारय, तारय संसार-सागरतः ॥}{षट्पदी स्त्रोत्रम्}

\end{document}


Yes, Sorry I placed this comment here. I have fixed it now.

Really like this solution - does the job and some more. Only downside is I now have to edit 100s of my verse blocks. Appreciate the showframe, didn't know I needed it.

Instead of overlapping, this will poke into the right margin.
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\addright}[2]{% #1 = centered, #2 = right justified
  \hbox to \linewidth {\phantom{#2}\hfill #1\hfill#2}\allowbreak
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
This is the first line of the poem \\
\addright{This is the second line of the poem}{--something}
\end{center}

\end{document}


This version pushes left instead of right.
\newcommand{\addright}[2]{% #1 = centered, #2 = right justified
  \makebox[\linewidth][r]{\phantom{#2}\hfill #1\hfill #2}\allowbreak
}


nice. only downside is it requires me to edit last line of each verse. This will definitely come to use when I write new verses. Appreciate it!
